# D3.v4 graph freezes when re-rendered

Tags: d3.js

I am porting my D3.v3 code to the latest D3.v4. I used to invoke my rendering **simulation** function additional times after my data changes (additional nodes, additional links, etc).

Now, if i invoke again my render function the graph **freezes**, and it does not adjust new nodes or links and dragging won't work either.

Following is the code in jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/za0xpdc5/4/

```
Graph.prototype.render = function() {
  this.simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) {
      return d.id;
    }))
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
    .force("center", d3.forceCenter(200, 200)); 

  link = this.linksG
    .selectAll("line")
    .data(this.links)
    .enter()
    .append("line")
    .attr("id", function(d) {
      return d.id
    });
  node = this.nodesG
    .selectAll("g")
    .data(this.nodes)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("id", function(d) {return d.id;})
    .append("circle")
    .attr("id", function(d) {return "node_" + d.id})
    .attr("r", 5)
    .call(d3.drag()
          .on("start", dragstarted)
          .on("drag", dragged)
          .on("end", dragended));

  # ==================================== 
  # <---- It appears the freeze occurs at this point
  #       during the 2nd execution  of graph.render()
  # ==================================== 

  this.simulation.nodes(this.nodes).on("tick", this.tick);
  this.simulation.force("link").links(this.links);
}
```

Comment: Well, it doesn't actually freeze, but you are messing up your selections. Your variables `link` and `node` are global and will get reassigned when `render()` is accessed the second time. That time, however, because your data hasn't changed, the enter selections will be empty which overwrites  `link` and `node` with empty selections. From thereon the `tick()` function has nothing to act upon. There are various solutions available. Choosing the right one will largely depend on your needs. Why are you calling `tick()` twice? Why do you create a new simulation? Why are those variables global?

Comment: Well said. I removed the simulation from that render function and defined a selector based on UI elements. This seems to resolve. I will update the JS Fiddle asap